# Chrome extension content script for extracting URL features

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, feature-extraction, content-script, phishing

This is only a snippet of code for building Chrome extension to detect phishing URL. The code below is to extract the URL features. What I do not understand is the purpose of `function predict(data,weight)`. What are the numbers in weight for ? Eg: `weight = [3.33346292e-01, ...]`

```
var testdata;
var prediction;

function predict(data,weight){
    var f = 0;
    weight = [3.33346292e-01,-1.11200396e-01,-7.77821806e-01,1.11058590e-01,3.89430647e-01,1.99992062e+00,4.44366975e-01,-2.77951957e-01,-6.00531647e-05,3.33200243e-01,2.66644002e+00,6.66735991e-01,5.55496098e-01,5.57022408e-02,2.22225591e-01,-1.66678858e-01];
    for(var j=0;j<data.length;j++) {
      f += data[j] * weight[j];
    }
    return f > 0 ? 1 : -1;
}

function isLongURL(){
    var url = window.location.href;    
    if(url.length<54){
        console.log("NP");
        return -1;
    } 
    else if(url.length>=54 && url.length<=75){
        console.log("Maybe");
        return 0;
    }
    else{
        console.log("P");
        return 1;
    }
}

testdata = [isLongURL(),isTinyURL(),isAlphaNumericURL(),isRedirectingURL(),isHypenURL()];

prediction = predict(testdata);

chrome.extension.sendRequest(prediction);
```

There are many other URL features function code but here I only included one example which is the checking for Long URL.

Comment: This multiplies each item in data with a specified factor, adds those up, and then checks if the result crosses a certain threshold ... How they _arrived_ at those exact numbers, you'd probably have to ask whoever wrote this in the first place though.

Comment: Ideally, the numbers should be derived from a statistical analysis of all known URLs that match the associated condition. It might be better to use machine learning though.

Comment: Actually, I do plan to use ML. I already coded NB-SVM ML using python separately. But I still do not have the idea on how to integrate this URL extraction features into the ML codes. How can I do it? @wOxxOm